# Unable to boot into Windows 10 after reinstalling GRUB using Boot-Repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Lately I've been having trouble with RAM so I was doing some testing when my PC froze while booting and I had to force shutdown.

After that, when I powered it on again I got the "Reboot and select proper boot device" error, so I guess my EFI partition corrupted. I decided to use boot-repair to fix it and after using it I was able to get into GRUB again, and my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installation is working properly, however when I try to boot into Windows 10 I get the following message:

```
/EndEntire
error: cannot find image.

Press any key to continue...
```

I tried running os-prober & grub-update multiple times but I always get the same error. I also tried creating my own menu entry like this:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10 (manual)' {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 56FC-8C94
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

but I get the same error. I've been looking all day for possible fixes but nothing seem to be working.

- Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qFw4S76xjd/
- grub.cfg: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/95qyqRWQdn/

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)' --class windows --class os  'osprober-efi-56FC-8C94' {"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=es_ES
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-56-generic-advanced-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-56-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-56-generic-recovery-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-56-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-52-generic-advanced-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-52-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-52-generic-recovery-4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt5  4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-52-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=4f250d13-643a-4a07-ba97-017639e29f95 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-56FC-8C94' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  56FC-8C94
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 56FC-8C94
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry 'Windows 10 (manual)' {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 56FC-8C94
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution: looks like I needed to repair Windows Boot Manager.

I downloaded Windows 10 installation tools into a USB drive, booted into it, ran the startup repair tool and now I'm able to boot into Windows 10 without any issue from GRUB.

I thought this was a GRUB configuration issue because of the error message I was receiving but I guess it wasn't?